# MariaDB not releasing RAM after jobs finish

Tags: memory-leaks, mariadb, ram

**TL:DR - It was likely a problem with Jemalloc not being turned on.  Now that Jemalloc is on, the problem appears to have gone away.**

---

Whenever I run a job to write to a database in MariaDB, it takes RAM to perform the operation.  However, even after the job has completed (and I can successfully query the database), the RAM is still being used.  This is becoming a problem, because after about 80 jobs, all of the system memory is being held hostage by MariaDB, and I have to restart it.  What would cause it to not release the RAM after finishing?

---

Update:

I recently moved from RHEL 7 to RHEL 8 to utilize column store, and thought that everything was copied exactly.  I'm noticing that Jemalloc is no longer on my computer, so that might be part of the problem.

I have modified the my.cnf, but it's a copy of the RHEL 7 file.  I have confirmed that the files are identical.  I did not have this issue on RHEL 7.

Some other applications are running, but I'm confident in calling MariaDB the villain.  While watching MariaDB in htop, I can see the MEM% increase when a database load starts.  Back in RHEL 7, I would see it decrease after a job finished.  However, I'm not seeing that now.  The other applications go about their business as normal.  Nothing else consumes an egregious amount of RAM, and the system runs fine until MariaDB builds up too much.

"80 jobs" is a bit of a misnomer.  I am not running 80 things at the same time.  80 is just the approximate number after which MariaDB builds up too much, which can take a few days.  The jobs definitely are completing.  I use Open Grid Scheduler (OGS) as a resource manager for my jobs.  I can see them clearing the running jobs state, and entering finished jobs.  After that, I can query the databases with mysql, and see the updated results.  In RHEL 7, this is also when MariaDB's MEM% would start to decrease.  I do not think that they are still connected, although I am open to suggestions for ways of verifying this.

I have plenty of RAM for the amount of dataloads I am performing to not interfere with routine processes and application use.  OGS helps ensure this by limiting the number of dataloads that can happen simultaneously.  I used this same setup when I had RHEL 7.  Based on past usage, I would not expect MariaDB to exceed 10% of my MEM%.  I'm not using innodb, I actually use myisam.  As such, my.cnf does not have `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

For now, I can keep running things while working on debugging.  At any time, I can kill and restart MariaDB to free up the memory it was holding.  I have been doing this once it reaches about 80% of MEM%.

For what it is worth, variations of the `FLUSH` statement have done nothing.  When I attempt them, I quickly get the message "Query OK, 0 rows affected", and the RAM usage remains the same.

---

Added snippets to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/SLaWxfjc

---

**I'd like to thank the people who have been helping me.  I think I have fixed the issue.  When using RHEL 7, I was using jemalloc.  When I moved to RHEL 8, it wasn't enabled and I thought it wasn't even installed on the machine.  However, I found it lurking about somewhere unexpected and under an assumed name, trying to start a new life of leisure without having to do work.  I've now put it back to work (which also involved updating the name in /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.cnf -> Environment=LD_PRELOAD=libjemalloc.so.2), and it appears that MariaDB is releasing RAM upon job completion.  So, configuration management, consistency, and carefulness were once again my worst enemies.  I'm going to be performing stress testing, but it appears to be working properly for now.**

It also happens that what worked for me was suggested as an answer to an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60430448/mysterious-mariadb-10-4-1-ram-ussage?rq=1) by user @GABRIEL.

Comment: This DATAWENEED - DWN-DB.bat script may work for you, if you connect to your instance with root login.
# If Linux OS, adjust the folder/directory path for your tee output destination. 
tee c:/temp/DWN-DB-last-tee.txt;   
SELECT NOW(); 
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
STATUS; 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables; 
SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables
LIMIT 100000; 
notee; 
end of script example.

  and 
Post the entire output into pastebin.com and share the link.

Comment: This DATAWENEED - DWN-OS.bat script may work for you, when using your admin login. 
# If Linux OS, adjust the folder/directory path for your tee output destination. 
tee c:/temp/DWN-OS-last-tee.txt; 
top -b -n 1 
top -b -n 1 -H 
htop 
ps -aux 
ulimit -a iostat -xm 5 3 
mpstat -P ALL 
df -h 
free -h 
cat /proc/meminfo 
notee; 
end of script example.
 and Post the entire output into pastebin.com and share the link

Comment: With the 2 batch files above, you will gather all the data into 2 tee output files without multiple copy/paste operations and we will be able to read and use your data to assist. Each BATch file will take less than 2 minutes to complete. This should not be considered to be lazy, just time saving.

Comment: If you could post TEXT results of 15 seconds of General Log output to pastebin.com and share the link, we could confirm that generally each 'Connect,Process,Close' has followed the pattern as referenced in this URL  -  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/connect/   Similar pattern should exit for nodejs, php-fpm, php, C#, others that CONNECT to your server.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've written the DWN-DB.bat and am waiting for results.  I don't understand the DWN-OS.bat.  Is everything with the tops supposed to be one long command?  Or are both tops, the htop, ulimit, iostat, mpstat, df, free, and cat separate commands?

When I do get outputs, I will try my best to copy them over.  However, hand copy is still the best method I have.  I may be able to rig something to get the files printed.  If so, I can scan them in and upload the scans as a pdf.  Would that help?

Comment: I've maxed out my memory while testing.  I need to restart MariaDB.

Comment: The OS.bat is to be multiple lines, top..... htop .... ulimit .... iostat, etc. and you will not have to hand copy anything.  If you can request data after 24 hours of uptime, it will be more meaningful.   You can get the General Log, anytime on a busy day for just 15 seconds.

Comment: The output of the 2 BAT files will be the file you name on the "tee c:/temp/DWN-xx-last-tee.txt command line (adjusted to survive Linux world).  It is closed when done with the line that simply has "notee; " as the line.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then.  I specified a different directory for my tee file, but the rest is as it appears in your comment (with line separation and semicolons at the end of each command).  However, when I run it, it hangs for a long time.  Using tail on either output file returns nothing.

Comment: Test the tee, not in a batch file until you figure out where your can put the output to a directory you have permissions to write in.  Just a 'cd' and press enter will record your current directory name, no matter where you are.   then "notee" and press Enter to close the tee activty.  check the output file with maybe sudo?  In a batch file you do not normally have ; semicolons at the end of the line like you would for a SELECT xxxx; in mysql.

Comment: The SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; can run more than a minute, but it is rare to take that long.

Comment: Okay, I ran tee from the terminal and threw in some commands to test it.  This resulted in it echoing and recording all of the commands I entered.  Neither "notee;" nor "notee" ended the recording, so I stopped it with ctrl+c.  It looks like the text file recorded verbatim what I entered, not the expected output of any command.

Comment: Then you can not use tee as a typical Linux user can.  Sorry, back to Copy/Paste and do the best you can.   tee and notee would be entered at a command prompt without the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jemalloc had a slightly different name when I moved to RHEL 8, and my partial copying and partial reinstallation of files from RHEL 7 meant that I had a configuration mismatch.  I had to find where Jemalloc now was, as well as updating the name in the following:

```
/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.cnf 
Environment=LD_PRELOAD=libjemalloc.so.2
```

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB would like to use a bunch of RAM for caching.  As you perform certain operations, it will glom onto more RAM.  But there is a max that is tunable.  Or, rather, each of the caches have a tunable limit of how much RAM they grab.

Did you modify the configuration (my.cnf)?  Arbitrarily raising configuration `VARIABLES` is a quick way to blow out memory.

Do you have lots of other applications running on the same server?  Maybe they are grabbing memory, too.  And it just seems like MariaDB is the villain.

Are those "80 jobs" continuing to be connected?  Or have they finished?

How much RAM do you have?  And what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Shrinking that `VARIABLE` may let you keep running while you debug the problem further.

Aha!  **MyISAM** lets the OS cache *data* blocks.  But that does not explain why they are connected with MariaDB.  What is `key_buffer_size`?

Comment: I've updated the question to provide more detailed answers to your questions.

Comment: @DavidRobie - After it has been up for at least a day (and before it dies), please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES` and the RAM size.  I may be able to find the problem.

Comment: @DavidRobie - I added a little.  Are you using ColumnStore yet?

Comment: I am using columnstore, and it appears to be working (except possibly this memory leak).  I've run the two commands, but it has generated ~1200 lines of information, and unfortunately hand copying is my only transfer method for now.  key_buffer_size is 134217728 (bytes?).  Since I'm too lazy to hand copy this entire output, is there anything specific that would help?  In the meantime, I'll look for a way to move the output to my windows machine.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unsuccessful in moving the output over to my windows machine.  I have two USB ports: one which my keyboard is plugged into, and one which doesn't work.  I have neither a CD drive, an ethernet port, nor a wifi card.  I do have a connector for a wifi antenna, but I have not seen the antenna in a few years, and it was not where I hoped it would be.

Comment: @DavidRobie - re Hand-copying:  Is it a big text string?  CSV?  other?

Comment: Check for a cheap device that splits on USB port into 3 (or maybe 7).

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: I queried mysql from the command line with the -t -D settings, so it's a few tables delimited by the "|" character.  Between the tables, I've got over 1200 lines of data.  I can convert it into a csv if that's preferred.  I might need to go out in a few days to get a usb splitter like you said.  I might have an idea for a workaround with my printer.  Would you be able to use a scanned sheet of paper?  Maybe I should look through and find the top 20 largest items.

Comment: Added pastebin link with my.cnf, show engines, and snippets of global status and variables.

Comment: See also `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...`

Comment: @DavidRobie Your snippets are too limited to be of value, except that you have a very BUSY system.  See the 2 BATch file examples you can use to quickly gather to data for analysis that Rick James, Me and a bunch of other people could use to assist you.